# Check if String contains other String C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find out if a String contains another string like this:

```
var s1 = "Test name*"
var s2 = "TestName"
```

If checked now it should return true.

Comment: `s1` does not contain `s2` and `s2` does not contain `s1` in your example, so it is unclear exactly what you are wanting from this.

Comment: Wait what? This should return true?  It's either duplicate or unclear or broken! Feel free to Use the mighty [Edit] Button!

Comment: This search with current value of s1 and s2 will return false.

Comment: It's a duplicate question.

Comment: Are you trying to check that if both strings have whitespace removed and you are not worried about capitalization that one could be contained in the other?

Comment: Basically, If 2 string Are obviously different with ahve to do classical string operation to check if different this way `"Tom Marvolo Riddle"` and `"I am Lord Voldemort"` return true.

Comment: It could be cool if the Function have a Culture invariant so `"Tom Servolo Riddle"`and `"I am Lord Voldemort"` return true too as It's the Spannish version of `"Eis Lord Voldemort"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var exists = s1.Replace(" ", "").Tolower().Contains(s2.ToLower());
```